# Installing nuget package from Gitlab to Ubuntu using VSCode

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, gitlab, nuget

I'm having trouble using a specific nuget package downloaded from gitlab. We are either getting a error "NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source" or a 401 error when retrieving information from the source.

```
nuget source Add -Name "GitLab" -Source "https://Organization.git.com/packages/nuget/index.json" -UserName git.Organization.com\Username -Password PersonalAccessToken
```

When we look at the command "nuget sources", the value comes up as enabled.

```
 1.  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ [Enabled]
      https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/
  2.  GitLab [Enabled]
      https://Organization.git/packages/nuget/index.json
```

However, when we look at the nuget list source using the following comman "dotnet nuget list source --format detailed", not only do we not see the Gitlab source, we see a different version ofnuget.

```
Registered Sources:
  1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Regarding troubleshooting, we've added a nuget.config file that includes credentials

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear /> <!-- clear to make sure that everyone uses the same sources -->
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="GitLab" value="https://Organization.git.com/packages/nuget/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
  <GitLab>
  <add key="UserName" value="Username" />
  <add key="Password" value="Token" />
  </GitLab>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

How can we make sure that our nuget packages from gitlab are enabled and/or how can we pass credentials to gitlab? Thanks!

We have also gone through various usernames like git.organization.com\username, "username", and https://git.organization.com\username.